# Pointwise approximating identity by compact operators

Tags: hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory

Does there exist a sequence of compact operators (not necessarily linear) $T_n: H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that, for every $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n\|T_n(u) - u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)}=0?
$$

For example, let us denote by $\chi_n$ the characteristic function of the ball $B(0,n)\subset\mathbb{R}^N$. Then, the operators $T_n:H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ given by the formula
$$ 
T_n(u) = \chi_n u
$$
are compact (in view of Rellich–Kondrachov theorem) and, for every $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\|T_n (u) - u \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)}=0,
$$
but I know nothing about the rate of convergence.

Recall that the operator $F$ from a Banach space $X$ to another Banach space $Y$ is *compact*, if the image under $F$ of any bounded subset of $X$ is a relatively compact subset of $Y$.

Comment: Did you try a standard mollification procedure?

Comment: Yes, I did but there is a problem with compatness of the convolution operator. Consider the smooth cutoff funtion $\phi\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^N)$, $\phi=1$ on $B(0,1)$ and supp$\phi\subset B(0,2)$. Define the sequence $u_n(x) = \phi (x- ne_1)$, where $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)\in\mathbb{R}^N$. Then $(u_n)$ is bounded sequence in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Take some mollifier $\rho$. Now, consider the sequence of convolutions $(\rho\ast u_n = \rho\ast \phi(\cdot - ne_1))$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$. It cannot have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: I see. And if you combine mollification with cut-off, e.g., $T_n(u) = \chi_n \, (\rho_n \star u)$?

Comment: Then, it would be a compact operator, but the rate of convergence is unknown for me. Consider the function $$u(x) = \begin{cases}1,\quad |x|<1,\\ \frac{1}{x},\quad |x|\geq 1\end{cases}.$$ Then $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$ and we have $$\chi_n (\rho_n\ast u) - u = \chi_n(\rho_n\ast u - u ) + (1-\chi_n)u.$$ Note that $\|(1-\chi_n)u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)}=2/n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a partial answer. If we demand that $T_n$ is a linear compact operator then the construction is impossible.
Indeed, assume there is a sequence of compact linear operators $(T_n)$ such that for every $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ we have
$$
\lim_{n\to infty} n\|T_n u - u \| = 0.
$$
Let us denote $L_n = n(T_n - I)$, where $I$ is the identity. By the Banach-Steinhaus theorem (uniform boundedness principle), since $L_n$ is pointwise bounded, there is $M> 0$
$$
\forall n\qquad \|L_n\| \leq M,
$$
in the operator norm. Therefore, we have
$$
\|T_n- I \|\leq \frac{M}{n}\iff T_n \to I\text{ in }\mathcal{L}(H^1,L^2)
$$
a contradiction, since $I$ is not a compact operator.